# How to make a cat feel comfortable with wearing clothes?

Tags: cats, training, attire

I live in a very cold house. Now that we are in the coolest time of the year, my cat spends the day looking for places to warm up and hide and does nothing else. It's a bit sad because he is a very playful cat and now he doesn't do anything.

She doesn't like having anything on his body. How can I get her used to wearing a jacket?

Besides the cold weather, I would like to dress her just because it might be fun.

Comment: How cold does it get in your house?

Comment: *"Besides the cold weather, I would like to dress her just because it might be fun"* Not for your cat. Cats spend most of the day sleeping or grooming. If you cover your cat with cloths, it won't be able to do one of the two things it really lives for. This will stress it out. Put out some blankets, the cat will stay warm. Cats can survive pretty cold weather outdoors without clothes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be completely up to the temperament of your cat whether or not they would accept wearing clothes. In my experience, most cats dislike the sensation of wearing things, but I’ve seen a few “popular” cats on Instagram that regularly wear coats.

If I were going to train my cat, I’d treat it like the harness training I did (be prepared, this may take months):

1. In a relaxed state and with treats, a few minutes each day, put the jacket on the cat.
2. Always be encouraging, but then don’t leave it on for too long.
3. Reward the cat and praise them.
4. Let them wear it longer and longer as they start to get comfortable (walking normally, returning to standard activities), until it becomes routine to wear the coat.

A couple important things to note about a jacket — make sure it:

- does not restrict any of your cat’s daily activities (I.e., using the litter box, jumping up a cat tree, curling up to sleep).
- is made of comfortable and safe material.

My house occasionally gets cold, so I keep a pet-safe hot pad out for my cat all the time. Definitely provide your cat with one or more warm space. Consider getting a space heater for the cat’s favorite room, too, if your house is really too cold for your cat.